# Openshift: Hide templates in playground project

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

How do I hide the default templates that are there in openshift project by default. I do not want users to use any of those templates and use only the one I create for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete all templates in openshift project using `oc delete template --all -n openshift`.
You can also first backup these templates in case you want them back. `oc export template -n openshift > templates.yaml`

Comment: Also delete the image streams ?